# SonarQube: only pom files push to sonar for multi-modules project

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Project has structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgipB.png)

```
my-project
  
  |--base
      |--src
      |--target
      |--pom
  |--uiFramework
      |--src
      |--target
      |--pom
  |--apiFramework
      |--src
      |--target
      |--pom
  |--uiJourneyTemplate
      |--src
      |--target
      |--pom
|--pom
|--sonar-project.properties
```

where POM file has:

```
<modules>
    <module>base</module>
    <module>uiFramework</module>
    <module>uiJourneyTemplate</module>
    <module>apiFramework</module>
</modules>
```

Each module in POM file has parent section.

in the main folder sonar-properties file has:

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.projectKey=com.java.framework:FRAMEWORK
sonar.sources=src
sonar.java.binaries=**/*
sonar.exclusions=**/*.js, uiJourneyTemplate/**/*
#sonar.java.libraries=**/*.jar

#List of module identifiers
sonar.modules=base,uiFramework,apiFramework

#base settings
base.sonar.projectName=com.java.framework:base
module1.sonar.sources=src/main/java

#uiFramework settings
uiFramework.sonar.projectName=com.java.framework:uiFramework
uiFramework.sonar.sources=src/main/java

#apiFramework settings
apiFramework.sonar.projectName=com.java.framework:apiFramework
apiFramework.sonar.sources=src/main/java
```

I tries different variations.

In the result I see that in sonar I have only one java file form base module and POM files from each modules:
in the console for others java file I have:

```
ERROR: Unable to create symbol table for : 'uiFramework/src/main/java/utils/waitings/SmartWait.java'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

the same for ALL others classes

what can u recommend?

thanks

SOLVED:
problem is: NOT possible to use JAVA 17 with SOnarQube 7.9.1 for now - need to use JAVA 11 and will work fine!
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-only-pom-files-push-to-sonar-for-multi-modules-project/57369/4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: @Jens hi, thanks for answering, no, problem is not with JAVA, smith with sonar configuration 100%

Comment: You shouldn't use `sonar-project.properties` for Maven project. Remove the file, execute the scan and it should work OOTB.

Comment: @agabrys it doesn't help - the same. My command is: /Users/myUser/Downloads/sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-macosx/bin/sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=FRAMEWORK \
  -Dsonar.host.url=url \
  -Dsonar.login=login \
  -Dsonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes \
  Dsonar.exclusions=**/*.js,uiJourneyTemplate/**/*,uiFramework/src/test/java/**/* \
  -Dsonar.java.libraries=**/*.jar

Comment: You have Maven, so use it. [SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/).

Comment: SOLVED: problem is: NOT possible to use JAVA 17 with SOnarQube 7.9.1 for now - need to use JAVA 11 and will work fine! https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-only-pom-files-push-to-sonar-for-multi-modules-project/57369/4